# SQL Select only one entry

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

Say I have a table like so:

```
ID        Description
1        A popular place to eat!
1        A popular place to eat!!
1        A popular place to eat!!!
2        Lets go!
2        Everyone, Lets go!
```

And I just want one of the descriptions for each ID, since they are different in irrelevant ways:

```
ID        Description
1        A popular place to eat!
2        Everyone, Lets go!
```

How can I write a SQL query to generate table 2 from table 1?

Comment: what if Descriptions are different in `relevant way`? is this an option in your case? what would you do in such case?

Answer (score 4):

Group by the column you want to be unique and use any aggregation function on the `description` column like `min()` or `max()`

```
select id, min(description)
from your_table
group by id
```